# How to stop Dynamic timer by clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

I have a scenario there i need to add timer dynamically. It means i need to display no of records from database with timer at end. I have done with the following code.

My Timer Function in JavaScript

timer.js

```
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time){
    var oop=this;
    this.Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
    this.TotalSeconds = Time;
    this.update();
    oop.to=setTimeout(function(){ oop.tick(); }, 1000);
}

CreateTimer.prototype={
    tick:function(){
    var oop=this;
    if (this.TotalSeconds <= 0){
        return;
    }
    this.TotalSeconds -= 1;
    this.update()
    oop.to=setTimeout(function(){ oop.tick(); }, 1000);
},

update:function(){
    var Seconds = this.TotalSeconds,Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
    Seconds -= Days * 86400;
    var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
    Seconds -= Hours * (3600);
    var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
    Seconds -= Minutes * (60);
    var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") +
    LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)
    this.Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
}, 

stop:function(){
    clearTimeout(this.to);
}
}

function LeadingZero(Time){
    return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;
}
```

and my code that adds timer dynamically is,

timertest.php

```
foreach($records as $value){
    $i = 1;
    // Displaying other datas in table datas at the end i have added my image
        echo '<td>
        <span id="timer"+$i>
            <img src="path/to/image/" id="myimg" />
        </span>
        </td>';
}
```

while click on that i have replaced my image with my timer

```
{
    // other codes
    timer+i = new CreateTimer('timer'+i, 60);
}
```

Its working fine only. Its displaying the timer as i think. I need to stop the timer while clicking on that. I dont have any idea to do that.

Please help me with that issue.

Comment: onclick event, or function that fires on clicking certain id?

Comment: @royalBg : I can use onclick event. but in there i can't pass that particular timers object. actually i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a feature you want  all timers to include, I'd encapsulate it. like this:

```
//...
function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time){
    var oop=this;
    this.Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
    // here. add Event listener to the DOM element
    var self = this; //save self
    this.timer.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.stop();
    });
    // ## end ##
    this.TotalSeconds = Time;
    this.update();
    oop.to=setTimeout(function(){ oop.tick(); }, 1000);
}
//...
```